# How are "unique IDs" generated for 1wire devices?

Tags: 1-wire

If I wanted to make my own 1wire device, I would need to give it a "globally unique" 48-bit identifier.

How are these identifiers generated? How can we guarantee no identifier conflicts with another brand's devices?

Comment: If you're going to downvote my question, at least have the balls to tell me why.

Comment: probably because the question is not about Arduino

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess is your question got downvoted because it's not about Arduino.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I must've forgotten to write "make my own 1wire device FOR USE WITH AN ARDUINO" to the sodding question!

Comment: Where would you _suggest_ I post it?

Comment: `forgotten to write "make my own 1wire device FOR USE WITH AN ARDUINO"` ... that would not make the question about the Arduino ... read what you are actually asking

Comment: There isn't a "making 1wire devices" SE. Where else was I supposed to ask!?

Comment: Well, NOT electronics.se, apparently! Am I supposed to keep guessing?

Comment: I think electronics se is the correct site for your question. Don't worry too much about downvotes.

Comment: Since there would be 2^48 unique IDS (281,474,976,710,656) then even a randomly-generated one would probably be safe. And since you say it is for the Arduino, just check there aren't other devices on the one-wire with a clashing ID. Are you going to have your devices *and someone else's* on the same wire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. After searching for a while I have not found a definite answer, but some good hints.

The 1-wire protocol was created by Dallas, which as later bought by Maxim Integrated. Thus the company Maxim has now control over it. They market the protocol with the explicit feature, that each device, that they manufacture, has a unique ID/serial number. They are the ones controlling it. I'm not sure how it works with other manufacturers, though this uniqueness probably only covers Maxims devices and the ones, where the respective manufacturer has a corresponding agreement with Maxim.

So you cannot be sure, that any ID you generate is unique in the group of all other devices. You can try to use a different family code in the device address (the 48bit is only a part of the actual address, together with 8 bit family code and 8 bit checksum), specifically one, that is currently not in use by Maxim. I've found [this technical article](https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/1wire-software-resource-guide-device-description.html) with a list of 1-wire device families. It states, that it may not include all device families, but it is the only list, that I found.

As you wrote "we": Creating IDs unique to a whole industry can only be guaranteed by going into an agreement with major industry players (provided they want to do such agreements). Otherwise your guarantees are always limited. You can stay away from the most common devices (with an unused family code) and make sure, that your organization gives out each device ID only ones.